# ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in UsersController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While applying logging concept to my book catalog display, when a user is regestering I am coming acorss this sort of error.

```
   Can't mass-assign protected attributes: password_confirmation, password
```

And my code in app/model/user.rb is as follows:

```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessible :name, :password_digest
     validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
     has_secure_password 
   end
```

And my code of create method in app/contollers/user_controller.rb

```
     def create
     @user = User.new(params[:user])

       respond_to do |format|
       if @user.save
       format.html { redirect_to users_url, :notice => 'User #{@user.name} was   successfully                  created.' }
    format.json { render :json => @user, :status => :created, :location => @user }
      else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.json { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
    end
    end
```

Any help please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to assign those values in the way you're doing it, you need to add them to the `attr_accessible` in your model:

```
attr_accessible :name, :password_digest, :password, :password_confirmation
```

I suspect you may not want to assign both of those, so you might want to delete them from that hash first (in the controller):

```
user = params[:user]
user.delete(:password_confirmation)
@user = User.new(user)
```

You could also create a new hash containing just the values you want to use to create the new `User`, if you have only a few values to keep but a lot of values to ignore.

(You could also create a new "empty" `User` and just assign the values you want - if that makes more sense in your situation.)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. And again whats happening is, when the user got registered, the current page is moved to user_url where users list is displayed...this is what it is displaying..

     User #{@user.name} was successfully created.

the user name is not getting displayed!!